# Get all fields from custom field model

Tags: python, django

I have a model:

```
class Companies(models.Model):
   ..
    managers = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="managers", blank=True)
```

View

```
class CompaniesList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    queryset = Companies.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CompaniesSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
```

Serializer

```
class UsersInCompanySerializer(PrimaryKeyRelatedField, serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id',
                  'first_name',
                  'last_name',
                  'email',
                  'is_active',
                  'is_staff',
                  'last_login',
                  'created_date')


    class CompaniesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        managers = UsersInCompanySerializer(many=True, queryset=User.objects.all().filter(groups__name='manager'))

        class Meta:
            model = Companies
            fields = ('id', 'managers', .....)
```

But when I get the JSON, I have field `managers` only `id`, like this:

```
   "managers": [
                "6b7f40f2-73a7-43cb-b1b7-4e24374495e8"
            ],
```

How I can view all the fields in `managers` like this:

```
 {
            "id": "97727151-8724-443a-a1c8-
            "first_name": "",
            "last_name": "",
            "email": "admin@gmail.com",
            "is_active": true,
            "is_staff": true,
            "last_login": "2018-03-27T18:23:43.868368Z",
            "created_date": "2018-03-27T14:54:33.566971Z"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening due to `managers = UsersInCompanySerializer(many=True, queryset=User.objects.all().filter(groups__name='manager'))`

As you have mentioned managers in field list so indirectly it is showing all fields from `UsersInCompanySerializer`